# TYPOSCRIPT stdWrap.replacement I Want to replace space with underscore _

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

My typo3 version is 10.4.22

```
lib.spaces = TEXT
lib.spaces {
   current = 1
   stdWrap.replacement {
       10 {
           search = 
           replace = _
           wrap = |
       }
   }
}
```

I have a following typoscript. And now my question is, what i have to write in search = ?
so that space is being searched and replace with underscore.

SORRY For my bad english!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replacement.search` has stdWrap, so you can use `char`. The ascii code for space is 32, so that will make it:

```
lib.spaces = TEXT
lib.spaces {
   current = 1
   stdWrap.replacement {
       10 {
           search.char = 32
           replace = _
           wrap = |
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is even an example in the official docs: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/10.4/en-us/Functions/Replacement.html#examples